# How do I pass the system_program to process_instruction?

Tags: rust, solana

I need to pass the `system_program` to the function. The function needs an `AccountInfo` type but I imported it as a module or a `Pubkey` and i do not know how to make it an `AccountInfo` type. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

I left out some of the other accounts that I passed to `process_instruction`

```rust
    use solana_program::{
            account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
            entrypoint,
            entrypoint::ProgramResult,
            program::{invoke_signed, invoke},
            system_instruction,
        system_program::ID as SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ID,
        system_program,
    };
    
    pub fn process_instruction(
        program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the hello world program was loaded into
        accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say hello to
        _instruction_data: &[u8], // Ignored, all helloworld instructions are hellos
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        msg!("Hello World Rust program entrypoint");
    
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
        let user = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let forecast_ai = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let question = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let system_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    
        let (forecast_key, fore_bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[user.key.as_ref(), question.key.as_ref()],
            program_id,
        );
    
        invoke_signed(
            &system_instruction::create_account(
                user.key,
                forecast_ai.key,
                Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(42),
                42,
                program_id
            ),
            &[user.clone(), forecast_ai.clone(), system_program.clone()],
            &[&[user.key.as_ref(), question.key.as_ref(), &[fore_bump]]],
        );enter code here
    
    
    
    let system = AccountInfo::new(
                &SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ID,
                false,
                true,
                &mut lamports4,
                &mut sys_data,
                &owner,
                false,
                Epoch::default(),
            );
    
    /**irrevelant code here*/
    
            let accounts = vec![user_ai, forecast_ai, question_ai, system];
            process_instruction(&program_id, &accounts, &instruction_data).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass in the `system_program` as one of your `AccountMeta` instances in the account list from client (in Rust):

```rust
AccountMeta::new(solana_sdk::system_program::id(), false)
```

Comment: This makes an AccountMeta type but it is asking for an AccountInfo type

Comment: @user14929084 Which you get in the program in the AccountInfo array. All accounts passed into an instruction in the AccountMeta array are resolved by Solana before your program/instruction is invoked.

Comment: I want to run it in a test. can you show the code of how to import and use system_program

Comment: That is a separate SO question altogether, check: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/debugging-solana-programs.html#facts